# Force unwrap or use optional chaining to set property

Tags: swift, forced-unwrapping, optional-chaining

Given an optional var `pinImageView: UIImageView?` which has properties that are set, I'm not sure which way is preferred to set the property. For example:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "Pin") {
    pinImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    pinImageView?.restorationIdentifier = "pin"
}
```

or

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "Pin") {
    pinImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    pinImageView!.restorationIdentifier = "pin"
}
```

Comment: The answer to _which is preferred_ can be Opinion based when there's no widely accepted way. This site seems not appropriate to gather such opinions.

Comment: Force unwrap(`!`) is always discouraged as it can crash your app. In the above example although `pinImageView` is initialized just before using the force unwrap(`!`) on it and it will work as expected with both approaches above but still i would recommend the first approach. Avoid making habit to a problematic approach.

Comment: @OOPer How would I know in advance for sure that this question is opinion based? One way might be considered wrong.

Comment: Maybe when your question is closed.

Comment: There's a third option, too:`if let image = UIImage(named: "Pin"), let view = UIImageView(image: image) { view.restorationIdentifier = "pin" }`

Comment: I would use a local non optional variable

Comment: @Kamran `!` *is not* discouraged. It has legitimate use cases. Sometimes you just cannot handle the case any other way. It's not a good idea to claim that your app won't crash but create undefined app behaviors instead. Also, often I see people avoiding `!` but still adding `fatalError()` all over their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which way is preferred

It is generally accepted that you should avoid `!` (*force unwrapping*) which is just begging for a crash, so this use should be avoided:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "Pin") {
    pinImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    pinImageView!.restorationIdentifier = "pin"
}
```

In this case, since you've just assigned `pinImageView`, force unwrapping it is safe, **but** it still raises red flags to you or anyone else who reads your code in the future.  "Ugh, they're using force unwrap here.  Could that crash?  Well, could `pinImageView` be `nil`?  No, it was just assigned in the previous line, so it's OK."  Why put yourself and others through this thought process; avoid the `!` whenever possible.

**This usage:**

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "Pin") {
    pinImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    pinImageView?.restorationIdentifier = "pin"
}
```

is safer because it uses *optional chaining* to unwrap `pinImageView` and avoids the *crash operator* `!`, but it still unwrapping an optional variable.

**A third alternative:**

The reason the imageView is optional is that you've assigned it to an optional variable.  If instead, you use a `let` constant to hold the object while you configure it, you can avoid filling your code with unwrapping code:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "Pin") {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.restorationIdentifier = "pin"
    pinImageView = imageView
}
```

This method works well when you are assigning many properties to the object since you can avoid many unwrapping operators.

Don't worry about the *extra line of code*.  The compiler will optimize that out.  Code for readability and clarity.

Comment: would you say that the second optional chaining way is fine when there is only one property getting assigned?

Comment: @bhartsb, it is fine.  I'd probably do that if assigning just a single property.  But by the time you're assigning two or three, the optional chaining starts to stand out.

Answer (score 0):

We have a code style/review rule in our team along the lines of "**No** use of the ! operator without a comment describing why it's safe".

Because ! destroys all the advantages of nil-safety in Swift, and casual use of it is asking for crashes and drags the language back to C/C++/Java/C#/Javascript/etc NullPointerException hell.

So in your case the

```
pinImageView?.restorationIdentifier = "pin"
```

option would definitely be preferred.

Comment: Thanks I was on the fence about the solution to accept.